# How to read and set CSRF token in Java (Prevent XSRF Security Token Missing)

Tags: java, bitbucket, csrf

In our Company we use BitBucket with our company URL: git.our-company.com

Now I want to create a new repository - automated by a Java application.

When I try to call the post-method I receive : `XSRF Security Token Missing`

I understand the basic concepts of CSRF (also called XSRF).
But what I am struggeling with is **how to read this CSRF Token?**
Where is it located / is there one place e.g. in a HEADER or hidden field?
Also how do I pass the token? I saw code like this : `post.addRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token",csrf);` which seems pretty easy.

As said the application is BitBucket.

Comment: Use the [API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.12.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp173) instead.